# VS Code unable to use PHP Intellsense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to use PHP IntelliSense while using WSL environment but VScode is unable to find PHP path. What I should do fix this? I searched for some info but I only see scripts but none worked for me.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

Comment: did you specify the path to the php.exe in the settings?

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not using PHP in windows, I'm using WSL with a LAMP instalation and when i set the WSL PHP path, VSCode doesen't recognize PHP Path.

Answer (score 1):

Try `bash -c "php"`.  WSL exposes a `bash.exe` binary on Windows, and if everything is correct it will already be in the environment variables, just by invoking it as `bash` - At least here, where I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.

You try also, `wsl -- "php"` or `wsl --exec "php"`.

**UPDATE: Forget what I said above !!**

Use the [Remote - WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) . I believe you're already using it.
Add the following directive to the `settings.json` file:
`"php.validate.executablePath":"php"`

the `php` binary must be properly available in $PATH on the Linux side.

And on Windows you need to have the path of the php windows version binary in the system environment variables, so that when you happen to be editing PHP files in the Windows File System - Not using the WSL remote - it uses the same binary.

This way you will have a VSCode that, when you are remote in WSL will use the proper lecture, being the same for when you are in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to [download php for Windows](https://windows.php.net/download) into the folder `c:\php` and specify in Visual Studio Code  `settings.json`:

```json
   "php.executablePath": "c:\\php\\php.exe",
```

I also added it to my [Windows PATH environment variable](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).